# Trying to make it every 5th token

Tags: java, for-loop

Trying to print first token then every 5th after. has error not a statement

```
for (x = 0; x <= secretWord.length(); x + 5)
        {
            //Print
            System.out.println(tokens[x]);
        }
```

Comment: for(test; initialize; update)

what am i missing?

Comment: shouldn't it be x <= secretWord.length() other wise it won't print any thing

Comment: first add int before x to initialize it then you have to add each iteration to the variable x, by doing x + 5 you are not adding to x so it should be x = x+ 5 or x +=5

Comment: Google "How to make a for loop in java". [And get rewarded](https://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You've not initialized `x`
- You can't have an expression dangling in the `for-loop`. You need to assign it to the variable `x` to make sense. Something like `x = x + 5`
- Your condition is wrong `x >= secretWord.length()`. It should be `x <= secretWord.length();` else your loop will not pass the first check and will never execute.